# C fscanf problems with reading ",," in a csv file

Tags: csv, scanf

Basically, it outputs everything in console just fine except when it hits empty spaces in between commas. There are no empty commas until the end so everything up until then prints well but then it hits an empty comma and the next data to be printed is supposed to be a "N" or "Y" but it prints a "s" instead. Is there a way to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>//
#include <stdlib.h>//
#include <string.h>//
#include "airPdata.h"//

/*read a line from file or until EOF*/
void readLine(char buf[], FILE *fipo);
/*parse buffer to struct*/
int printData(airPdata* airport, FILE *fipo);
/*main function*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])//Parameters in int for command line use
{
    FILE *fipo;//File pointer
    fipo = fopen(argv[1], "r");//Opens fipo file pointer with read permission

    if (fipo == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "etl ERROR: File %s not found.", argv[1]);//Prints error message STDERR indicating which specific file is missing
        return (1);//Exits safely
    }//Ends if statement

    char buf[500]; /*buffer for lines from file*/
    int valid; /*check if line is valid*/
    airPdata* airport;//Declaring airPdata

    airport = (airPdata*)malloc(sizeof(airPdata)); /* allocated the memory needed */
    airport->siteNumber = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->LocID = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->fieldName = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->city = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->state = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->useless1 = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->useless2 = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->useless3 = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->latitude = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->longitude = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->useless4 = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->useless5 = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->useless6 = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
    airport->useless7 = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));

    printf("%-13s%-11s%-45s%-45s%-7s%-16s%-16s%-5s\n", "FAA Site#", "Short Name", "Airport Name", "City", "ST", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Tower");
    printf("%-13s%-11s%-45s%-45s%-7s%-16s%-16s%-5s\n", "=========", "==========", "============", "====", "==", "========", "=========", "=====");
    printData(airport, fipo);
    fclose(fipo);//Closes the fipo file

    free(airport->siteNumber);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->LocID);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->fieldName);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->city);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->state);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->useless1);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->useless2);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->useless3);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->latitude);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->longitude);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->useless4);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->useless5);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->useless6);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport->useless7);//Returns previously allocated memory
    free(airport);//Returns previously allocated memory
    return 0;//Exits
}//Ends main function

int printData(airPdata* airport, FILE *fipo)
{
    char line[128];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        i = 0;
        while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fipo ) != NULL )
        {
            fscanf(fipo, "%[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %[^,]%*c %c", airport->siteNumber, airport->LocID, airport->fieldName, airport->city, airport->state, airport->useless1, airport->useless2, airport->useless3, airport->latitude, airport->longitude, airport->useless4, airport->useless5, airport->useless6, airport->useless7, &airport->controlTower);
            printf("%-13s%-11s%-45s%-45s%-7s%-16s%-16s%-5c\n", airport->siteNumber, airport->LocID, airport->fieldName, airport->city, airport->state, airport->latitude, airport->longitude, airport->controlTower);//Displays output
            i ++;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read your question again

Comment: Ok I did. What are you hinting at? EDIT: Oh I forgot the code. it's up now